# Finding (not set) Values in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have a client that is having issues with a portion of users sending (not set) as the value for their first pageview (landing page). I suspect a problem with the Tag Management Software configuration, but I can't be sure beacuse I have not been able to query this in BigQuery.

I don't see values for any of the following WHERE clauses: `hits.page.pagePath IS NULL`, `hits.page.pagePath = '(not set)'`, or `hits.page.pagePath = ''`

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: Can you take a sampling of the values (e.g. `SELECT hits.page.pagePath FROM ... LIMIT 1000;`)? Maybe that would help identify what's stored for the (not set) entries.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is trying to find the different values to them query them later. I couldn't find any documentation on how the ga export deals with " not set" ( a pretty common case)

If that's not successful you can try auditing the tag manager triggers and rules. But you'd need access to it. Testing on your browser is not always great but can spot things that are way off

Answer (score -2):

Just find like a string
= '(not set)'

Any doubts just say

Comment: Haven't OP already said that he can't find any values with this criteria in his WHERE clause?